# How to add Multiple Choice Questions with Correct Answers in Google Quiz

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

This is the [google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1pXwuJSX2T9mTDNYjnvVpDE84SyYx7VaXDWrska0Ker8/edit?usp=sharing) [ESH - B1.1 - Exam 2]

Google Script is: examMakerQA

I am very new to scripting. In the sheet, I wish to add True / False to the options of Multiple Choice Questions [Col P to Col Z]. So that I don't have to manually add correct answers in Google Form.

```
//Make Multiple-Choice question
function makeMultipleCQ(d, form){
  var mcItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  mcItem.setTitle(d[1]);
  if(d[2] !== "N"){mcItem.setPoints(d[2])};
  if(d[4] === "Y"){mcItem.setRequired(true);}
  
//Filter blank cells
  var options = d.splice(5,10);
  var options = options.filter(function(x){return x !== ""});
  var corrects = d.splice(15, 20); // data with true, false 
  var corrects = options.filter(function(x){return x !== ""});
     
//Loop through options and add to question  
  **var ch = options.map(function(option, op){
  var tf = false;
  if(op === d[3]){tf = true};
    
  return mcItem.createChoice(option, tf)** 
  });
  
  mcItem.setChoices(ch);
  
  var correctFeedback = FormApp.createFeedback()
      .setText(d[3])
      .build();
  mcItem.setFeedbackForCorrect(correctFeedback);
  
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you are comparing the index `op` against the answer key in column D.

**What you need to do instead is to evaluate the entries in columns P to Z corresponding to the index `op` against `TRUE` or `FALSE`**

To do this you can modify your code as following:

```js
function makeMultipleCQ(d, form){
  var mcItem = form.addMultipleChoiceItem();
  mcItem.setTitle(d[1]);
  mcItem.setTitle(d[1]);
  if(d[2] !== "N"){mcItem.setPoints(d[2])};
  if(d[4] === "Y"){mcItem.setRequired(true);}
  
  //Filter blank cells
  var options = d.splice(5,10);
  var options = options.filter(function(x){return x !== ""});
  //after the previos splice the original array and consequently the indeices has been modified
  var ops = d.splice(5,10);
  var ops = ops.filter(function(x){return x !== ""});
  //Loop through options and add to question  
  var ch = options.map(function(option, op){
    var tf = ops[op];
    return mcItem.createChoice(option, tf); 
  });
  
  mcItem.setChoices(ch);  
  var correctFeedback = FormApp.createFeedback()
  .setText(d[3])
  .build();
  mcItem.setFeedbackForCorrect(correctFeedback);  
}
```